# Find ActiveRecord objects created or updated in a time range

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `ActiveRecord` model with the standard `created_at`, `updated_at` timestamps. I want to run a query to find all records created or updated in a time range.

It possible to do this in a single ActiveRecord query?

The following works great for a single clause (just querying on `created_at`, for example).

```
range = 2.weeks.ago .. 1.week.ago
=> Mon, 03 Jun 2013 14:49:54 UTC +00:00..Mon, 10 Jun 2013 14:49:54 UTC +00:00

Item.where(:created_at => range)
  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE (`items`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2013-06-16 14:40:55' AND '2013-06-17 14:40:55')
=> [... results ...]
```

When I try to add the second clause `ActiveRecord` is producing an `AND` statement, which is not what I want:

```
Item.where(:created_at => range, :updated_at => range)
  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`
    WHERE (`items`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2013-06-16 14:40:55' AND '2013-06-17 14:40:55')
    AND (`items`.`updated_at` BETWEEN '2013-06-16 14:40:55' AND '2013-06-17 14:40:55')
```

I could do the query with a single statement and add the results to a set to remove duplicates, but it really feels like something that should be a possible on once query.

And ideas?

Comment: `Where` arguments are AND'd, that's how that works. If you want more complex conditions, roll your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write your own statement if you want to `OR` two conditions together:

```
Item.where("(created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) or (updated_at BETWEEN ? and ?)", 2.weeks ago, 1.week ago, 2.weeks_ago, 1.week_ago)
```

Answer (score 4):

You overcomplicate your code by searching for `created_at` AND `updated_at`. You only need to search for `updated_at` because that gets set at a create too. So the solution for your problem is:

```
range = 2.weeks.ago .. 1.week.ago
Item.where(:updated_at => range)
```

Comment: That's not quite the same - if an item was edited today, the updated_at field would be updated to today, and thus it would fall out of the search.

Answer (score 0):

check out `gem "squeel"` it will definitely help you out. Its really awesome. A railscast on this is also there:

https://github.com/ernie/squeel

http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel?view=asciicast